Firebase service account- Firestore working on dev server but not working after deployment to firebase hosting
When I run my Sveltekit application locally my backend Sveltekit load functions work as expected, requesting data from from Firestore database with the admin sdk. When I deploy the website with firebase deploy the page throws a status 500.
The reason I think the issue is related to the admin SDK is because I changed the load function to send only an empty object and it worked as expected, the page loaded fine. I could be wrong.
//firebase admin initialization

import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import serviceAccount from './serviceAccountKey.json';

if (admin.apps.length === 0) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });
}

const firestoreAdmin = admin.firestore();

export { firestoreAdmin };



//svelte +page.server.js load function

import { firestoreAdmin } from "$lib/firebaseAdmin.js";

export async function load() {
    let pivots = {};
    let fuel;
    let settings;

    const pivotsColRef = firestoreAdmin.collection('pivots');
    const fuelDocRef = firestoreAdmin.doc('inputs/fuel');
    const settingsDocRef = firestoreAdmin.doc('settings/settings');

    try {
        const pivotsColSnap = await pivotsColRef.get();
        const fuelDocSnap = await fuelDocRef.get();
        const settingsDocSnap = await settingsDocRef.get();

        pivotsColSnap.forEach(object => {
            pivots[object.id] = object.data();
        });

        fuel = fuelDocSnap.data();
        settings = settingsDocSnap.data();

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    return {
        props: {
            pivots: pivots,
            fuel: fuel,
            settings: settings,
            error:"no error",
        }
    }
}

This is the error i am getting in the cloud log, but it is still working fine on my dev server.

{ "textPayload": "FirebaseAppError: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.\n at AppStore.getApp (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/lifecycle.js:65:19)\n at FirebaseNamespaceInternals.app


"not working" is really hard to help with, and a staatus code 500 is not much to go on either. Is anything more written to the Cloud Functions logs?

{
"textPayload": "FirebaseAppError: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.\n    at AppStore.getApp (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/lifecycle.js:65:19)\n    at FirebaseNamespaceInternals.app

This is the error i am getting in the cloud log, but it is still working fine on my dev server.
